# ApostropheCMS keeps loading when 'New Page' is clicked

Tags: loading, apostrophe-cms

I just installed ApostropheCMS and want to make a new page. But when I click 'New Page', it keeps loading.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anybody know what's the issue?

Thanks in advance,

Jeffrey

Comment: Do you have any output from either/both the browser console or the server console? Can you detail a little bit about your environment and installation process?

Comment: One type error that says cookie is not a function and two times blocked loading mixed active content for two font files... I work with nodejs.

Comment: Feels like you have a front end JS issue that is blocking the modal experience. Do you have any custom JavaScript at project level? Was New Page ever working?

Comment: The cookie error suggests maybe you threw in another version of jQuery and lost ours... Or we missed something in the recent upgrade to jQuery 3. I'll check that.

Comment: OK, I just created a new project with the apostrophe cli and verified that I can create a new page with no problems.

Jeffrey, can you push up a test project that demonstrates the bug?